# Variadic function: Checking number of arguments

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, variadic-functions

I have a variadic function that runs some code on the first argument and then runs `NSString` `initWithFormat:arguments:` afterwards, if arguments have been passed in.

```
+ (NSString *)updatedString:(NSString *)mainString, ...
{
    // Some code run on mainString here, outputs finalString

    // add format arguments to the final string
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, mainString);
    NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:finalString arguments:args];
    va_end(args);

    return formattedString;
}
```

**EDIT:** The idea is that the code run on mainString uses a regular expression to find and replace variables within the text. So say the output (`finalString`) equals `"Hello World %@ blah blah %@"`, then it would use the arguments to replace the `%@` symbols. The issue is that I don't know if the resolved string includes `%@` symbols or not until the string is resolved.

So, I need to check to see if there are actually any extra arguments, and if there aren't, I don't want to run the `initiWithFormat` part.

Is there any way to check if `args` exists first?

Comment: Why do you need the check? Calling `initWithFormat` is fine even if there are no more args as long as the format string has no format specifiers.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot modify the updatedString method so you can explicitly pass in the number of variable arguments?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying achieve. Because now you code looks totally wrong. May be passing arguments with NSArray argument will suit you better.

Comment: I have updated the question slightly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. In C/Objective-C a called variadic function has absolutely no idea about the number and types of arguments passed by the caller. It must figure it out somehow based on other information (e.g. for format arguments, that they match the format specifiers in the format string; or for objects to initialize a Cocoa collection, that the list is terminated with `nil`) and trust that the caller correctly followed the convention.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I was trying to "be clever" and have the function formatted in the same way as `initWithFormat`, but I could just as easily pass an array of arguments instead. Looks like that I will have to go with that instead. Thanks!